# Escrever no Excel usando Python

Tags: python

Estou usando python para automação, onde preciso setar uma serie de informações na planilha.

Entendo que preciso de 2 `for`, um para percorrer linha e o outro a coluna, preciso definir um limite pois cada linha e coluna tem que ir até `j`. Queria saber como seto as informações na planilha dentro desses 2 `for`. Sei como setar mas não dentro de um `for`.

Estou usando biblioteca `openpyxl` `import` `load_workbook`

O código está assim:

```
max_linha = sheet.max_row

max_coluna = sheet.max_column

for i in range(1,max_coluna + 1)

 for j in range(1,max_linha + 1)
```

Para setar eu faço assim:

```
sheet[A1] = "Ok"
```

Seria algo do tipo?

```
sheet["A"][i][j] = variavel
```

Comment: Isso não é uma dúvida da linguagem. Você deve procurar a documentação das bibliotecas que está usando. Se ainda tiver problema, tem de oferecer um script curto porém completo, desde os imports, para alguém se dispor a testar e sugerir conserto.

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar a biblioteca pandas? Ela trabalha bem melhor com arquivos CSV's (se for o caso). Ela cria dataframes que é possível acessar todas as linhas/colunas com o for, ou atráves de chaves, ou ainda quebrar o dataframe em determinava linha/coluna com as funções "loc" e "iloc". A sua pergunta está bem superficial, poste um código mais completo para entendermos melhor o problema ou ser possível de testa-lo.

Comment: Obrigado pedro, dei uma pesquisada  acho que será melhor usar o pandas mesmo, principalmente por conta da questão do dataframes.  vou pesquisar como fazer caso eu tenha alguma  duvida  volto aqui.  obrigado...